# how can I replace [link](#) to <a href="#">link</a>?

Tags: php, regex, string, str-replace

I want to do something like *stackoverflow*. actually changing this style `[]()` to this style `<a href=""></a>`. here is my try:

```
$str = '[link](#)';
$str = str_replace('[','<a href="',$str);     // output: <a href="link](#)
$str = str_replace(']','">',$str);            // output: <a href="link">(#)
$str = str_replace('(','',$str);              // output: <a href="link">#)
$str = str_replace(')','</a>',$str);          // output: <a href="link">#</a>
```

but now, I need to change `link` with `#`, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to take a look at [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), with this you can use a regex to replace it, e.g.

```
$str = preg_replace("/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/", "<a href='$2'>$1</a>", $str);
```

regex explanation:

```
\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)
```

- **\[** matches the character [ literally
- 1st Capturing group **(.*?)**

  - **.*?** matches any character (except newline)

    - Quantifier: ***?** Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
- **\]** matches the character ] literally
- **\(** matches the character ( literally
- 2nd Capturing group **(.*?)**

  - **.*?** matches any character (except newline)

    - Quantifier: ***?** Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
- **\)** matches the character ) literally

Comment: very good, worked correctly, but one new question, why your pattern `/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/` does not works in javascript ?

Comment: @stack Because you asked a PHP question. And js regex are sometimes a bit different

Comment: ah I see, I thought the patterns are identical in all languages, anyway thanks.

Comment: also your explanation is great...! I always was afraid of regex, but now it is more understandable for me.

Comment: Look, As well as I need to javascript of above pattern. do you know javascript ? or I ask a new question for javascript ? I tried, but I could not find it (javaScript version).

Comment: @stack Never really played with js regex, so can't answer it. (Maybe you find a quick solution if you ask nicely in the js or regex chat room)